# Rollback After Deployment Developer Edition

Tags: deployment, developer-edition, developer-org

Are there any ways to rollback after deployment for Developer Edition?
Besides we'll keep a back up. I would love to discover more.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Once fully deployed, there is no way to reverse such a deployment. This is true in any org. You should definitely consider using [Unlocked Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_intro.htm) and Git. Backups are only as useful as they are updated. Using a proper code repository means you can restore individual files, review a history of changes, and so much more. Consider something like the [SFDX & Github Trail Mix](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/users/rvanh/trailmixes/sfdx-git-hub), which I'd say is a short introduction to a proper development cycle.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge